# Visual Studio, Filter on error list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, castle-monorail

I 'm working with Visual Studio 10, my project is with monorail and I get a lot of error on my ".vm" files, those errors are not pertinent, and I don't want to see them anymore is there a way.
I tagged this ask with castle monorail, because I guess some users could have the same problem. But I'm sure it's a problem more general.

I get the same problem sometime with aspx or xslt visual studio check the file's validity ( with the own rules) and report the errors in the error list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New Answer:

Unfortunately, these errors are emitted by CVSI, and can be ignored - I agree they're a bit annoying. I've found that they go away if I re-open the solution. Not a great answer, but it's the only one I've found that works.

## Previous Answer:

Are these errors `ObjectDisposedExceptions`?

What are your settings WRT exception handling in VS.NET? Go to `Debug -> Exceptions` in the menu. If there's a check in the "Thrown" column, then you need to open that up and then find `System.ObjectDisposedException` and then deselect it.

If you're looking to still break on deselected exceptions which are thrown elsewhere, you're out of luck, as this isn't currently supported by VS.NET.

Comment: they are not Exception but compilation error, I get Build Succeeded, Execution work well, it's just VS who detect errors in files whete it mustn't not look.

Comment: I'm confused: "build succeeded" usually means NO compilation errors. If you're getting compilation errors, this means you may be trying to compile your *.vm files, which isn't correct. They get interpreted by the ViewEngine at runtime.

Comment: I get the same problem sometime with aspx or xslt visual studio check the file's validity ( with the own rules) and report the errors in the error list.

Comment: Oh THAT problem - yeah, I've seen that too. My experience is that these errors are removed from the error list after a successful debug session, or closing and re-opening the solution.

Comment: Yep, I beleive I will make a addon to filter thoses errors... because it's a shame and horrible to deal with.

Comment: If you're interested in helping out, the best solution would be to provide a patch [here](https://github.com/jonorossi/cvsi) so these errors are never emitted.